# why does sum need GHC.Num.fromInteger?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a 3d vector data type defined as 3 floats. I understand that if I provide a `Num` instance for my class and define the normal mathematical operators, I can use them on my class.

```
data Vec3 = Vec3 { x :: Float
                 , y :: Float
                 , z :: Float
                 } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Num Vec3 where
  (+) v1 v2 = Vec3 (x v1 + x v2) (y v1 + y v2) (z v1 + z v2)
```

When I load my file into ghci, I get warnings because I didn't define all the functions in `Num`, which makes sense.

```
Prelude> :l temp.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( temp.hs, interpreted )

temp.hs:6:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `*'
    In the instance declaration for `Num Vec3'

temp.hs:6:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `abs'
    In the instance declaration for `Num Vec3'

temp.hs:6:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `signum'
    In the instance declaration for `Num Vec3'

temp.hs:6:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `fromInteger'
    In the instance declaration for `Num Vec3'
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

However, I can still use the ones I've defined.

```
*Main> let a = Vec3 1.0 2.0 3.0
*Main> let b = Vec3 2.0 4.0 5.0
*Main> a + b
Vec3 {x = 3.0, y = 6.0, z = 8.0}
```

My confusion comes from the following error I get when trying to use the sum function

```
*Main> sum [a,b]
Vec3 {x = *** Exception: temp.hs:6:10-17: No instance nor default method for class operation GHC.Num.fromInteger
```

Why does sum need a `fromInteger` definition for my `Vec3` data type? For one, I would have figured that sum only uses the `+` function, and for another, my data type doesn't use  `Integer`.

Comment: You should always define **all** the operations in the minimal complete definition before consider the data type as an instance of a class...

Comment: The real problem here is that you're making `Vec3` an instance of `Num` even though vectors aren't numbers.

Comment: To expand on @rightfold - don't make something instance of Num just because you want + - vectors aren't numbers even if some of the operators you use on vectors tend to have the same name as number operators. (although you _can_ treat vectors as numbers if by 'vector' you just mean 'fixed size collection of numbers' instead of vector in a geometrical or physical sense).

Comment: @Cubic I understand where you're coming from. I'm used to overloading operators in C++, and it seems unfortunate that I can't robustly define a single operator for a data type in Haskell without it needing to be a number or without hiding `(+)` and doing a qualified import of Prelude. `vec3Add a b` is more annoying to type than `a + b`

Comment: The `vectorspace` package introduces functions like `^+^`, `^*`, `*^` etc for vector operations. Remember you're not limited to some fixed set of operators like in C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how sum is implemented:

```
sum = foldl (+) 0
```

Notice the `0` literal. Let's check it's type in GHCi:

```
λ> :t 0
0 :: Num a => a
```

As it turns out, numeric literals are sugar for `fromInteger`. Ie, `0` is actually `fromInteger 0`.

Thus, `sum` requires `fromInteger`, because the above definition is sugar for:

```
sum = foldl (+) (fromInteger 0)
```

---

The implementation of `fromInteger` is easy:

```
instance Num Vec3 where
    fromInteger n = let a = (fromInteger n) in Vec3 a a a
```

Furthermore, I would highly recommend that, whenever making an instance, always define it completely to avoid unforeseen trouble like this.

Comment: That makes sense. Tangential question, but where do I find the implementations of these common functions? I tried looking, but didn't know where to look

Comment: @user3288829 The source file is [`GHC.Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Num.html).

Comment: Thanks @phadej and AJFarmar, I'm still new to Haskell. I'll make sure to check those sources first next time

Comment: Yet the functions in `base` are hard to find, `sum` on lists is well hidden: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#sum

It's own exercise to lookup where it is in base-4.7 :)

Comment: obscure error messages like this make Haskell occasionally time wasting - i was puzzled  for a while and did not see how to give an implementation for fromInteger in a similar case (despite using Haskell for probably close to 20 years). perhaps somebody could add the example implementation in an easy to find place (e.g. in the Haddock comment of Num).

Answer (score 4):

What should `sum [] :: Vec3` return?

---

The [`sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-List.html#sum) function could be defined as

```
sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum =  foldl (+) 0
```

The `0` there is actually `fromInteger (0 :: Integer)`, thus you need `fromInteger` to use `sum`.

*Actually* in base-4.8 `sum` is defined in terms of `Sum` `Monoid` and `Foldable`, but that's different story. You still need `fromInteger (0 :: Integer)` there.