# fromInteger is a cast?

Tags: haskell, types, numbers

I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373070/why-does-sum-need-ghc-num-frominteger), as well as contemplating the whole issue of non-decimal literals, e.g., `1`, being just sugar for `fromInteger 1` and then I find the type is

```
λ> :t 1
1 :: Num p => p
```

This and the statement

> An integer literal represents the application of the function
> fromInteger to the appropriate value of type Integer.

have me wondering what is really going on. Likewise,

```
λ> :t 3.149
3.149 :: Fractional p => p
```

Richard Bird says

> A floating-point literal such as `3.149` represents the application of
> `fromRational` to an appropriate rational number. Thus `3.149 :: Fractional a => a`

Not understanding what *the application of `fromRational` to an appropriate rational number* means. Then he says this is all necessary to be able to add, e.g., `42 + 3.149`.

I feel there's a lot going on here that I just don't understand. Like there's too much hand-waving for me. It seems like a cast of an unidentified non-decimal or decimal to specific types, `Integer` and `Rational`. So first, why is `1` actually `fromInteger 1` internally? I realize every expression must be evaluated as a type, but why is `fromInteger` and `fromRational` involved?

**Auxillary**

So at [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers) page

> The workhorse for converting from integral types is `fromIntegral`,
> which will convert from any `Integral` type into any Numeric type (which
> includes `Int`, `Integer`, `Rational`, and `Double`): `fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`

Then comes the example

```
λ> sqrt 1
1.0
λ> sqrt (1 :: Int)
... error...
λ> sqrt (fromInteger 1)
1.0
λ> :t sqrt 1
sqrt 1 :: Floating a => a
λ> :t sqrt (1 :: Int)
...error...
λ> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
λ> :t sqrt (fromInteger 1)
sqrt (fromInteger 1) :: Floating a => a
```

So yes, this is a cast, but I don't know the mechanism of how `fromI*` is doing this --- since technically it's not a cast in a C/C++ sense. All instances of `Num` must have a `fromInteger`. It seems like under the hood Haskell is taking whatever you put in and generic-izing it to `Integer` or `Rational`, then "giving it back" to the original function, e.g., with `sqrt (fromInteger 1)` being of type `Floating a => a`. This is very mysterious to someone prone to over-thinking.

So yes, `1` is a literal, a constant that is polymorphic. It may represent `1` in any type that instantiates `Num`. The role of `fromInteger` must be to allowing a value (a cast) to be extracted from an integer constant consistent with what the situation calls for. But this is hand-waving talk at some point. I dont' get how this is actually happening.

Comment: It depends on how you define "cast".  Also, it helps to distinguish the literal `3.149` from the number it *represents*.  If you do, you can think of `fromRational 3.149` not as a decomposable expression that applies  function to a value generated from 3.149, but as a whole that the compiler can use to generate the necessary code involving the correct value.

Comment: Could you unpack this a bit more? I feel there's a CS degree behind your statement starting at "If you do...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help more.  One thing you seem to be struggling with is the nature of a value of type `Num a => a`, like the one produced by `fromInteger (1 :: Integer)`.  I think you're somehow imagining that `fromInteger` "packages" up the `1 :: Integer` in a box so it can later be cast by special compiler magic to a `1 :: Int` or `1 :: Double`.

That's not what's happening.

Consider the following type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Thing a where
  thing :: a
```

with associated instances:

```
instance Thing Bool where thing = True
instance Thing Int where thing = 16
instance Thing String where thing = "hello, world"
instance Thing (Int -> String) where thing n = replicate n '*'
```

and observe the result of running:

```
main = do
  print (thing :: Bool)
  print (thing :: Int)
  print (thing :: String)
  print $ (thing :: Int -> String) 15
```

Hopefully, you're comfortable enough with type classes that you don't find the output surprising.  And presumably you don't think that `thing` contains some specific, identifiable "thing" that is being "cast" to a `Bool`, `Int`, etc.  It's simply that `thing` is a polymorphic value whose definition depends on its type; that's just how type classes work.

Now, consider the similar example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Ratio
import Data.Word
import Unsafe.Coerce

class Three a where
  three :: a

-- for base >= 4.10.0.0, can import GHC.Float (castWord64ToDouble)
-- more generally, we can use this unsafe coercion:
castWord64ToDouble :: Word64 -> Double
castWord64ToDouble w = unsafeCoerce w

instance Three Int where
  three = length "aaa"
instance Three Double where
  three = castWord64ToDouble 0x4008000000000000
instance Three Rational where
  three = (6 :: Integer) % (2 :: Integer)

main = do
  print (three :: Int)
  print (three :: Double)
  print (three :: Rational)
  print $ take three "abcdef"
  print $ (sqrt three :: Double)
```

Can you see here how `three :: Three a => a` represents a value that can be used as an `Int`, `Double`, or `Rational`?  If you want to think of it as a cast, that's fine, but obviously there's no identifiable single "3" that's packaged up in the value `three` being cast to different types by compiler magic.  It's just that a different definition of `three` is invoked, depending on the type demanded by the caller.

From here, it's not a big leap to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import Data.Ratio
import Data.Word
import Unsafe.Coerce

class MyFromInteger a where
  myFromInteger :: Integer -> a

instance MyFromInteger Integer where
  myFromInteger x = x
instance MyFromInteger Int where
  -- for base >= 4.10.0.0 can use the following:
  -- -- Note: data Integer = IS Int | ...
  -- myFromInteger (IS i) = I# i
  -- myFromInteger _ = error "not supported"
  -- to support more GHC versions, we'll just use this extremely
  -- dangerous coercion:
  myFromInteger i = unsafeCoerce i

instance MyFromInteger Rational where
  myFromInteger x = x % (1 :: Integer)

main = do
  print (myFromInteger 1 :: Integer)
  print (myFromInteger 2 :: Int)
  print (myFromInteger 3 :: Rational)
  print $ take (myFromInteger 4) "abcdef"
```

Conceptually, the base library's `fromInteger (1 :: Integer) :: Num a => a` is no different than this code's `myFromInteger (1 :: Integer) :: MyFromInteger a => a`, except that the implementations are better and more types have instances.

See, it's not that the expression `fromInteger (1 :: Integer)` boxes up a `1 :: Integer` into a package of type `Num a => a` for later casting.  It's that the type context for this expression causes dispatch to an appropriate `Num` type class instance, and a different definition of `fromInteger` is invoked, depending on the required type.  That `fromInteger` function is always called with argument `1 :: Integer`, but the returned type depends on the context, and the code invoked by the `fromInteger` call (i.e., the definition of `fromInteger` used) to convert or "cast" the argument `1 :: Integer` to a "one" value of the desired type depends on which return type is demanded.

And, to go a step further, as long as we take care of a technical detail by turning off the monomorphism restriction, we can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

main = do
  let two = myFromInteger 2
  print (two :: Integer)
  print (two :: Int)
  print (two :: Rational)
```

This may look strange, but just as `myFromInteger 2` is an expression of type `Num a => a` whose final value is produced using a definition of `myFromInteger`, depending on what type is ultimately demanded, the expression `two` is *also* an expression of type `Num a => a` whose final value is produced using a definition of `myFromInteger` that depends on what type is ultimately demanded, even though the literal program text `myFromInteger` does not appear in the expression `two`.  Moreover, continuing with:

```
  let four = two + two
  print (four :: Integer)
  print (four :: Int)
  print (four :: Rational)
```

the expression `four` of type `Num a => a` will produce a final value that depends on the definition of `myFromInteger` and the definition of `(+)` that are determined by the finally demanded return type.

In other words, rather than thinking of `four` as a packaged `4 :: Integer` that's going to be cast to various types, you need to think of `four` as completely equivalent to its full definition:

```
 four = myFromInteger 2 + myFromInteger 2
```

with a final value that will be determined by using the definitions of `myFromInteger` and `(+)` that are appropriate for whatever type is demanded of `four`, whether its `four :: Integer` or `four :: Rational`.

The same goes for `sqrt (fromIntegral 1)`  After:

```
x = sqrt (fromIntegral (1 :: Integer))
```

the value of `x :: Floating a => a` is equivalent to the full expression:

```
sqrt (fromIntegral (1 :: Integer))
```

and every place it is is used, it will be calculated using definitions of `sqrt` and `fromIntegral` determined by the `Floating` and `Num` instances for the final type demanded.

Here's all the code in one file, testing with GHC 8.2.2 and 9.2.4.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Haskell98 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Data.Ratio
import GHC.Num
import GHC.Int
import GHC.Float (castWord64ToDouble)

class Thing a where
  thing :: a

instance Thing Bool where thing = True
instance Thing Int where thing = 16
instance Thing String where thing = "hello, world"
instance Thing (Int -> String) where thing n = replicate n '*'

class Three a where
  three :: a

instance Three Int where
  three = length "aaa"
instance Three Double where
  three = castWord64ToDouble 0x4008000000000000
instance Three Rational where
  three = (6 :: Integer) % (2 :: Integer)

class MyFromInteger a where
  myFromInteger :: Integer -> a

instance MyFromInteger Integer where
  myFromInteger x = x
instance MyFromInteger Int where
  -- Note: data Integer = IS Int | ...
  myFromInteger (IS i) = I# i
  myFromInteger _ = error "not supported"
instance MyFromInteger Rational where
  myFromInteger x = x % (1 :: Integer)

main = do
  print (thing :: Bool)
  print (thing :: Int)
  print (thing :: String)
  print $ (thing :: Int -> String) 15

  print (three :: Int)
  print (three :: Double)
  print (three :: Rational)
  print $ take three "abcdef"
  print $ (sqrt three :: Double)

  print (myFromInteger 1 :: Integer)
  print (myFromInteger 2 :: Int)
  print (myFromInteger 3 :: Rational)
  print $ take (myFromInteger 4) "abcdef"

  let two = myFromInteger 2
  print (two :: Integer)
  print (two :: Int)
  print (two :: Rational)

  let four = two + two
  print (four :: Integer)
  print (four :: Int)
  print (four :: Rational)
```

Comment: First, let me commend you on this heroic effort to shine light into darkness. Now, I just tried your `Thing` class but get this error `Illegal instance declaration for ‘Thing String’ (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn) where T is not a synonym.` Any clues what I can do. Still dissecting, though.

Comment: It seems my original example only ran under GHC 9.2.4.  I've edited it so it runs on earlier GHC versions as well.  (I tested it on 9.2.4 and 8.2.2.)

Comment: This does help me greatly. But still the fact that a naked literal `1` just typed in triggers `fromInteger` amazes/baffles. Yes, `fromInteger :: Integer -> a` is set up in the class system for `Num`. Though your examples spoon-feed, i.e., `print (myFromInteger 2 :: Int)`. Again, the literal `1` is auto-magically told to be `fromInteger 1`, and naked `3.14` is told to be `fromRational 3.14` seems like deus ex machina. So no, this is not a brutalist C/C++ cast, but being able to invoke the class system just with a naked literal remains an incomplete story for me.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will help...

Imagine a language, like Haskell, except that the literal program text `1` represents a term of type `Integer` with value one, and the literal program text `3.14` represents a term of type `Rational` with value 3.14.  Let's call this language "AnnoyingHaskell".

To be clear, when I say "represents" in the above paragraph, I mean that the AnnoyingHaskell compiler actually compiles those literals into machine code that produces an `Integer` term whose value is the number 1 in the first case, and a `Rational` term whose value is the number 3.14 in the second case.  An `Integer` is -- at it's core -- an arbitrary precision integer as implemented by the GMP library, while a `Rational` is a pair of two `Integer`s, understood to be the numerator and denominator of a rational number.  For this particular rational, the two integers would be 157 and 50 (i.e., 157/50=3.14).

AnnoyingHaskell would be... erm...  annoying to use.  For example, the following expression would not type check:

```
take 3 "hello"
```

because `3` is an `Integer` but `take`'s first argument is an `Int`.  Similarly, the expression:

```
42 + 3.149
```

would not type check, because `42` is an `Integer` and `3.149` is a `Rational`, and in AnnoyingHaskell, as in Haskell itself, you cannot add an `Integer` and a `Rational`.

Because this is annoying, the designers of Haskell made the decision that the literal program text `42` and `3.149` should be treated as if they were the AnnoyingHaskell expressions `fromInteger 42` and `fromRational 3.149`.

The AnnoyingHaskell expression:

```
fromInteger 42 + fromRational 3.149
```

*does* type check.  Specifically, the polymorphic function:

```
fromInteger :: (Num a) => Integer -> a
```

accepts the AnnoyingHaskell literal `42 :: Integer` as its argument, and the resulting subexpression `fromInteger 42` has resulting type `Num a => a` for some fresh type `a`.  Similarly, `fromRational 3.149` is of type `Fractional b => b` for some fresh type `b`.  The `+` operator unifies these two types into a single type `(Num c, Fractional c) => c`, but `Num c` is redundant because `Num` is a superclass of `Fractional`, so the whole expression has a polymorphic type:

```
fromInteger 42 + fromRational 3.149 :: Fractional c => c
```

That is, this expression can be instantiated at any type with a `Fractional` constraint.  For example. In the Haskell program:

```
main = print $ 42 + 3.149
```

which is equivalent to the AnnoyingHaskell program:

```
main = print $ fromInteger 42 + fromRational 3.149
```

the usual "defaulting" rules apply, and because the expression passed to the `print` statement is an unknown type `c` with a `Fractional c` constraint, it is defaulted to `Double`, allowing the program to actually run, computing and printing the desired `Double`.

If the compiler was awful, this program would run by creating a `42 :: Integer` on the heap, calling `fromInteger` (specialized to `fromInteger :: Integer -> Double`) to create a `42 :: Double`, then create `3.149 :: Rational` on the heap, calling `fromRational` (specialized to `fromRational :: Rational -> Double`) to create a `3.149 :: Double`, and then add them together to create the final answer `45.149 :: Double`.  Because the compiler isn't so awful, it just creates the number `45.149 :: Double` directly.

Comment: So it does seem like non-decimal literals are cast as `Integer` and decimal literals are cast as `Rational`. I find, however, `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` and then `fromInteger 1 :: Num a => a` weird since `Num a => a`  would seem like a constraint, not a packaging/cast of `1` as an `Integer`. Intuitively I understand how something needs to happen to let unlike types that are still numbers be added, subtracted. But `take` accepts `3` as an `Int` when it's technically an `Integer` is baffling, too. It's getting casted from `Integer` to `Int`.

Comment: `Num a => a` says that for any `Num` type, the expression can be forced to be of that type.

Comment: Yes, but we seem to be taking a literal, in the form of, e.g., `fromInteger 1` or `fromRational 3.14`, into whatever numeric type the calling function needed it to be. e.g., the `sqrt` example I just added above needing a `Floating`. This is what I'm trying to understand. How does it get from, e.g., `sqrt (fromInteger 1)` to the proper `Floating` type required?

Comment: @147pm: `Num a => a` can be written out with `-XExplicitForall` as `forall a. Num a => a`. This is akin to a function of two parameters: `a :: Type` and `Num a :: Constraint`. By default, they’re filled in by type inference. You can pass `a` indirectly, with a type signature, as in `fromInteger 1 :: Int`; or directly, with `-XTypeApplications`, as in `fromInteger @Int 1`. These expressions have type `Num Int => Int`, which is equivalent to `Int` because `instance Num Int` is defined; it’s passed in implicitly by the compiler, along with many optimisations like inlining and unboxing.